# AngularJS Protocolo file://

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Galera, estou fazendo uma aplicação em AngularJS embarcada que quando o sistema (operacional, não a aplicação) inicia, ele abre o index.html que contém a aplicação feita em angular.

A primeira página funciona, mas como eu faço pra mandar ela pra outra página ?

Eu tentei usando rotas, mas como roda no protocolo **file://** eu não tenho um contexto onde eu consiga fazer /outrapagina.

Como posso fazer pra exibir outra pagina com outro controller?

Comment: A sua aplicação vai rodar no protocolo file ou isso é só pro desenvolvimento?

Comment: Ela vai rodar no protocolo file.

Comment: Acho que o primeiro problema ai é ver qual navegador vai ser usado, pois o protocolo `file://` não é bem padronizado, cada navegador tem suas próprias regras para ele

Comment: Vai ser rodado no QtWebkit. Até tivemos problemas com CORS mas conseguimos configurar isso no qtwebkit.

Comment: Eu fiz funcionar usando o bom e velho window.location.href. O problema que com isso, meu template não funciona..

Answer (score 0):

Para trabalhar com angular você precisa ter um servidor http. Entretanto você pode conseguir esse de forma muito simples.

**1- Instalar o nodeJs e gerenciador de pacotes do node chamado npm**

Sobre o node: https://nodejs.org/en/

Instalação nodeJs e npm: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node

**2- Criar variável de ambiente apontando para o diretório de instalação do nodeJs**

Link com a instrução: http://udgwebdev.com/node-js-para-leigos-instalacao-e-configuracao/

**3- Navegar até o diretório dos teus arquivos pelo prompt e rodar o seguinte comando: *http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1***

Esse comando irá subir um servidor http na porta 8000. Logo é só você abrir o browser e navegar pelos aquivos. http://localhost:8080/

**OBS: Existem gambiarras para rodar pelo protocolo file. Mais será um problema a longo prazo. Recomendo a utilização desse servidor http que é simples e poderoso.**

Comment: Cara, ele disse que quer rodar no protocolo **file**.

Comment: @jbueno Sim, e que estou dando é uma sugestão, pois não tem como rodar com o protocolo file